# regex in C doesn't match when egrep does

Tags: c, regex

The code:

```
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   unsigned   i;
   regex_t    regex;
   regmatch_t captures[2];
   char *     nmLines[] = {
      "0000000000000a10 t frame_dummy",
      "0000000000000a40 T geom_Init",
      "0000000000000b30 t geom_RectangleAllocate",
   };
   int errCode = regcomp( &regex, ".*\\W(\\w+_Init)\\W*", 0 );
   if( errCode ) {
      char errMsg[1024];
      regerror( errCode, &regex, errMsg, sizeof( errMsg ));
      fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", errMsg );
      return 1;
   }
   for( i = 0U; i < sizeof(nmLines)/sizeof(nmLines[0]); ++i ) {
      errCode =
         regexec(
            &regex,
            nmLines[i],
            sizeof(captures)/sizeof(captures[0]),
            captures,
            0 );
      if( 0 == errCode ) {
         printf( "Match : %s, between %d and %d\n",
            nmLines[i], captures[1].rm_so, captures[1].rm_eo );
      }
      else {
         printf( "Doesn't match : %s\n", nmLines[i] );
      }
   }
   regfree( &regex );
   return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
$ gcc -W -Wall -o rx rx.c ; ./rx
Doesn't match : 0000000000000a10 t frame_dummy
Doesn't match : 0000000000000a40 T geom_Init
Doesn't match : 0000000000000b30 t geom_RectangleAllocate
```

The same output filtered with egrep which matches one line between 3 (the right one):

```
$ ./rx | egrep '.*\W(\w+_Init)\W*'
Doesn't match : 0000000000000a40 T geom_Init
$
```

**Why `regexec` fail when `egrep` succeed with the same expression?**

Comment: There is no guarantee that your `regex` library supports the same regular expression syntax as `egrep`.  You need to read the documentation for the library and make sure that you're using a conforming regular expression.

Comment: What is this `sizeof(captures)/sizeof(captures[0])` ? There is only 1 capture group right?

Comment: In this case `sizeof(captures)/sizeof(captures[0])` returns 2: one for the whole expression, one for the captured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bug is fixed!

The expression I use is **POSIX Extended Regular Expression** not a **POSIX Basic Regular Expression**.

Amended code is:

```
int errCode = regcomp( &regex, ".*\\W(\\w+_Init)\\W*", REG_EXTENDED );
```

[Here is an extract of the documentation:](http://linux.die.net/man/3/regcomp)

- REG_EXTENDED : Use POSIX Extended Regular Expression (ERE) syntax when interpreting regex. If not set, POSIX Basic Regular Expression (BRE) syntax is used.

`regcomp` doesn't report an error because the expression is valid in `BRE` but has no meaning because `\W` doesn't act as a word boundary and `\w` as a word part. These characters are handled *as is*.

[Here is another helpful documentation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html#ere) about GNU extensions of the `ERE` like `\W` and `\w`

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple flags you can set when using regex functions on POSIX see http://linux.die.net/man/3/regexec
I believe the one that is causing your problem is
REG_ICASE
    Do not differentiate case. Subsequent regexec() searches using this pattern buffer will be case insensitive.

REG_EXTENDED
Is also a useful flag when using more complex regex features in c

Comment: No, I'm looking exact matching, not case insensitive matching.

Comment: maybe you could try the extended syntax flag then... or the full form of \W which is [^\w] ...